# Limitation of Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Is there any trial period limitation in firebase because i've recieved this message from google

Dear Developer,

Your Google Cloud project sky-prints was shut down on 2019-12-22T10:36:53+00:00.

Shut-down projects and the data stored in them may be recovered for a limited time before the projects are permanently deleted. If you’d like to recover your project, you must cancel the project’s permanent deletion before 2020-01-21T10:36:53+00:00.

To recover your shut-down project:

Visit the Resources pending deletion page.
Select the project you want to recover, and click Restore.
In the confirmation dialog, click Restore.
If you take no action by 2020-01-21T10:36:53+00:00, you will be unable to recover your project.

If you have any questions, please visit Google Cloud Platform Resource Manager Documentation or contact Google Cloud Platform Support.

I cant understand this

Comment: So you deleted a project, right?

Comment: I don't think so because I am using it for my personal use and currently my project is in the ideal state from past 4 to 5 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has different [**pricing plans**](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), which define the range of the products you can use and their limits.

The email you received, however, is related to the project [**deletion**](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137886?hl=en&ref_topic=6400762) - once your project is shut down, you have 30 days to restore it.

As stated in the email, in case of that particular project, you can cancel its permanent deletion before **2020-01-21T10:36:53+00:00**.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such trial period limitation you are using the Firebase Spark plan. You can add up to 5 projects, but if you are using further Firebase product then that depends.

However, this email is related to project you have deleted recently. You can add a new project or recover the existing with 30 days if you wish to.